# Switching color range into another using Gimp and specifying hex values

Tags: color, gimp, image-editing

I want to change the color of an object which has different shades of green into different colors and specifying hex as target colors. I want to change the object from green to any hex color I specify and supporting the shades of the green. I know I can switch colors using Rotate Colors feature of GIMP. Though I am limited by the colors on the wheel. I also explored the Exchange Colors option but changing the r/g/b thresholds causes other non-green colors to change. I only want to change the green color and nothing else. Is there an option to do what I want in GIMP?

Thanks.

Comment: *" I only want to change the green color"* The "By Color" selection tool has a "Select by" selector that lets you do selections around a given value of a specific R/G/B channel. You can also use the Channel mixer to make an image that represents your wanted selection (likely positive green, negative /red/blue), and then use that image as a selection (in the Channels list, right-click any of the R/G/B and `Channel to Selection`)

Comment: Do you have an example image you can share with us here? There are various methods possible but it really depends on the kind of image you are working with. Also does the image already have separate elements on different layers or is it a flat single layer image?

Comment: Here is what I am trying to accomplish. I have a green screen. I want to create LUTs (using the lutCreator.js tool( which can be used with videos with this green screen (I do not want to use chroma key because they make the background unrealistic looking). I combine the image from lutCreator.js with one still of the video (with the green screen) in GIMP then apply the filters I want. I have managed to change the green screen color into any of the color ranges available with rotate colors and create LUTs that work with those. Though, I want a specific hex color which I cannot reach in ...

Comment: ... the color wheel in GIMP. @xenoid

Comment: In the color selector you can always enter the hex code directly?

Comment: I am confused by your question. I looked up lutCreator.js and now understand how that works. Are you having trouble selecting a color range or are having trouble specifying a hex color?